# Java Splitting of strings from text File

Tags: java

I'm trying to split some strings from a text file which has tabs in between the integers. integer /t integer /t integer.

```
50      

1   2   46

1   15  38

1   16  43

1   21  4

1   25  24

1   35  2

1   43  6
```

I tried using string token but `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` came out, so i did some debugging myself and found out this.

How my codes look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Datas.txt"));
    String data;
    int i = 0;

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        data = input.nextLine();
        String[] sp = data.split("\\t+");

        String n1 = sp[0];
        System.out.println("|" + n1 + "|");
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Here's the picture link of the result when i compile and run it.[image]

Edit: No idea why the result turns out like this. Switched to bufferedReader and everything's good now. Thanks for the help people.

Answer (score 0):

This should split correctly

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    data = input.nextLine();
    String [] sp = data.split("\\s+");
    if(sp.lenght>1){
     String n1 = "|";
     for(String tmp:sp){
         n1=n1.concat(h);
     }
     n1=n1.concat("|");
     System.out.println(n1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried using String [] sp = data.split("\t");
String [] sp = data.split("\\s+");
String [] sp = data.split(" ");
all doesn't work.

Comment: @June now? Am assuming you want to print all integer strings b/w the pipes

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows

```
public static void main (String []args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("D:\\sample.txt"));
    String data;
    int i = 0;
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        data = input.nextLine();
        String [] sp = data.split("\t");
        String n1 = sp[0];
        System.out.println("|" + n1 + "|" );
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wont to use Scanner#nextInt() method.

```
File f = new File("Datas.txt");
Scanner scanner = null;

try {
    scanner = new Scanner(f);

    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
       scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do simpler

```
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String next = sc.next();
    }
```

it breaks both by spaces and new line